# JAVA simple fps animation(how can i work with?)

Tags: java, frame-rate

can you help me, how can i calculate and show fps in my animation?
I want only show simple rect (for example).

if i have code:

```
private final FPS = 30;
private final SIZE = 10;
private int x = 10;
private int y = 0;
private String myFps;

private void start(){
    while(true){
        moveRect();
        paint();
     }
}

private void paint(){
   g2.drawRect(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
   g2.drawString(myFps, 10, 10);
}

private void moveRect(){
   x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a copypaste of my very old simple Java Graphics+BufferStrategy gameloop test app. Animation loop draws few moving rectangles and fps counter.

> java -cp ./lib/test.jar GameLoop2 "fullscreen=false" "fps=60"
>   "vsync=true"

```
//http://www.javagaming.org/index.php/topic,19971.0.html
//http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch1/ch1.pdf

import java.util.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import java.awt.DisplayMode; // for full-screen mode

public class GameLoop2 implements KeyListener {
    Frame mainFrame;

    private static final long NANO_IN_MILLI = 1000000L; 

    // num of iterations with a sleep delay of 0ms before
    // game loop yields to other threads.
    private static final int NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD = 16;

    // max num of renderings that can be skipped in one game loop,
    // game's internal state is updated but not rendered on screen.
    private static int MAX_RENDER_SKIPS = 5;

    private static int TARGET_FPS = 60;

    //private long prevStatsTime;
    private long gameStartTime;
    private long curRenderTime;
    private long rendersSkipped = 0L;
    private long period; // period between rendering in nanosecs

    long fps;
    long frameCounter;
    long lastFpsTime;

    Rectangle2D rect, rect2, rect3;

    /**
     * Create a new GameLoop that will use the specified GraphicsDevice.
     * 
     * @param device
     */
    public GameLoop2(Map<String,String> args, GraphicsDevice device) {
        try {
            if (args.containsKey("fps"))
              TARGET_FPS = Integer.parseInt(args.get("fps"));


            // Setup the frame
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = device.getDefaultConfiguration();

            mainFrame = new Frame(gc);
            //mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
            mainFrame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            mainFrame.setSize(640, 480);
            //mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo();
            mainFrame.setLocation(700,100);
            mainFrame.createBufferStrategy(2);
            mainFrame.addKeyListener(this);

            if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(args.get("fullscreen"))) {
              device.setFullScreenWindow(mainFrame);
              device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480, 8, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN));
            }

            final boolean VSYNC = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(args.get("vsync"));

            // Cache the buffer strategy and create a rectangle to move
            BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = mainFrame.getBufferStrategy();

            rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(0,100, 64,64);
            rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Float(0,200, 32,32);
            rect3 = new Rectangle2D.Float(500,300, 128,128);

            // loop initialization
            long beforeTime, afterTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;
            long overSleepTime = 0L;
            int noDelays = 0;
            long excess = 0L;
            gameStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            //prevStatsTime = gameStartTime;
            beforeTime = gameStartTime;

            period = (1000L*NANO_IN_MILLI)/TARGET_FPS;  // rendering FPS (nanosecs/targetFPS)
            System.out.println("FPS: " + TARGET_FPS + ", vsync=" + VSYNC);
            System.out.println("FPS period: " + period);


            // Main loop
            while(true) {
               // **2) execute physics
               updateWorld(0);                  

               // **1) execute drawing
               Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
               drawScreen(g);
               g.dispose();

               // Synchronise with the display hardware. Note that on
               // Windows Vista this method may cause your screen to flash.
               // If that bothers you, just comment it out.
               if (VSYNC) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

               // Flip the buffer
               if( !bufferStrategy.contentsLost() )
                   bufferStrategy.show();

               afterTime = System.nanoTime();
               curRenderTime = afterTime;
               calculateFramesPerSecond();

               timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
               sleepTime = (period-timeDiff) - overSleepTime;
               if (sleepTime > 0) { // time left in cycle
                  //System.out.println("sleepTime: " + (sleepTime/NANO_IN_MILLI));
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep(sleepTime/NANO_IN_MILLI);//nano->ms
                  } catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                  overSleepTime = (System.nanoTime()-afterTime) - sleepTime;
               } else { // sleepTime <= 0;
                  System.out.println("Rendering too slow");
                  // this cycle took longer than period
                  excess -= sleepTime;
                  // store excess time value
                  overSleepTime = 0L;
                  if (++noDelays >= NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD) {
                     Thread.yield();
                     // give another thread a chance to run
                     noDelays = 0;
                  }
               }

               beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

               /* If the rendering is taking too long, then
                  update the game state without rendering
                  it, to get the UPS nearer to the
                  required frame rate. */
               int skips = 0;
               while((excess > period) && (skips < MAX_RENDER_SKIPS)) {
                  // update state but don’t render
                  System.out.println("Skip renderFPS, run updateFPS");
                  excess -= period;
                  updateWorld(0);
                  skips++;
               }
               rendersSkipped += skips;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateWorld(long elapsedTime) {
        // speed: 150 pixels per second
        //double xMov = (140f/(NANO_IN_MILLI*1000)) * elapsedTime;
        double posX = rect.getX() + (140f / TARGET_FPS);
    if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth())
        posX = -rect.getWidth();    
    rect.setRect(posX, rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());

        posX = rect2.getX() + (190f / TARGET_FPS);
    if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth())
        posX = -rect2.getWidth();   
    rect2.setRect(posX, rect2.getY(), rect2.getWidth(), rect2.getHeight());         

        posX = rect3.getX() - (300f / TARGET_FPS);
    if (posX < -rect3.getWidth())
        posX = mainFrame.getWidth();
    rect3.setRect(posX, rect3.getY(), rect3.getWidth(), rect3.getHeight());         

    }

    private void drawScreen(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, mainFrame.getWidth(), mainFrame.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 40, 50);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect((int)rect.getX(), (int)rect.getY(), (int)rect.getWidth(), (int)rect.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect((int)rect2.getX(), (int)rect2.getY(), (int)rect2.getWidth(), (int)rect2.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect((int)rect3.getX(), (int)rect3.getY(), (int)rect3.getWidth(), (int)rect3.getHeight());
    }

    private void calculateFramesPerSecond() {
        if( curRenderTime - lastFpsTime >= NANO_IN_MILLI*1000 ) {
            fps = frameCounter;
            frameCounter = 0;
            lastFpsTime = curRenderTime;
        }
        frameCounter++;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE ) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        Map<String,String> mapArgs = parseArguments(args);

            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            new GameLoop2(mapArgs, device);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Parse commandline arguments, each parameter is a name-value pair.
     * Example: java.exe MyApp "key1=value1" "key2=value2"
     */
    private static Map<String,String> parseArguments(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> mapArgs = new HashMap<String,String>();

        for(int idx=0; idx < args.length; idx++) {
            String val = args[idx];
            int delimIdx = val.indexOf('=');
            if (delimIdx < 0) {
                mapArgs.put(val, null);
            } else if (delimIdx == 0) {
                mapArgs.put("", val.substring(1));
            } else {
                mapArgs.put(
                    val.substring(0, delimIdx).trim(),
                    val.substring(delimIdx+1)
                );
            }
        }

        return mapArgs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, if i want show actual fps, where can i find it? in 'long fps;' ?

Comment: See drawScreen and calculateFramesPerSecond functions. I update "long fps" variable once every second. Its value is drawn on screen every render step.